# how to compare the date entered in textbox to the current date using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I check that the date entered in a textbox is less than today's date using java script?

I m using code

```
var currentDate_Month = new Date().valueOf().getMonth();
        var currentDate_Date = new Date().getDate();
        var currentDate_Year = new Date().getFullYear();
        var EnterDate_Month = new Date(document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateReceived').value).getMonth();
        var EnterDate_Date = new Date(document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateReceived').value).getDate();
        var EnterDate_Year = new Date(document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateReceived').value).getFullYear();

        if(EnterDate_Year<currentDate_Year) {
          if(EnterDate_Month<currentDate_Month) {
            if(EnterDate_Date<currentDate_Date) {
            }
           }
          }
         else {   
            str += '</br>* Date should be Less than or equals to current Date.';
            return false;
         }
```

But to my surprise the current date coming in the textbox control is Sat Jun 7 2014 when viewing it by -

```
new Date(document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateReceived').value).toDateString();
```

Why is it returning the date in this format? (the date in text box is in format dd/mm/yyyy)

thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue it seems is not with your comparison code but with the format in which you are initializing the new Date() using the textbox value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Date() can be initialized as

```
Date("mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Since this is the adopted method, the format of dd/mm/yyyy is not possible. The best method in your case will be to do the following

```
dateFields = (document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateReceived').value.split('/')

date = Date(dateFields[2],dateFields[1]-1, dateFields[0])
```

This would be in the format

```
Date(year, month, date)
```

Then, you can compare the textbox date with the present date

```
date < Date.now()
```

Comment: date[1]-1 would be better I believe

Comment: @mplungjan thanx. I forgot about that. you should have edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your code:

```
var today = new Date();

var enterDate = new Date(Date.Parse(document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateReceived')));

if (enterDate.valueOf() < today.valueOf())
{
    // To what you have to do...
}
```